# Domain and range of recursive functions are recursively enumerable

Tags: computability

I want to show the following two propositions:

- The domain of a recursive function is recursively enumerable.
- The range of a recursive function is recursively enumerable.

I have thought the following in order to prove the first proposition.

Suppose that we have a recursive function $f$. Then we know that there is an algorithm $A$ that computes $f$.
So if $m \in dom(f)$ then we know that the algorithm $A$ with input $m$ terminates, giving output "yes".
Since $m$ is arbitrary, we deduce that the domain of a recursive function is recursively enumerable.

Is my idea right? If so, can't we also deduce from that that the domain of a recursive function is recursive since the algorithm always terminates for the elements of the domain?

Can you give me a hint how we can show the second proposition?

Answer (score 2):

The first proof looks ok. (Actually, it depends on the definition you use for RE. Some authors define RE iff it's the domain of a recursive function, making the exercise trivial.)

For the second, here's a hint. Given $x$ you want to check whether $f(0)=x$ or $f(1)=x$ or ... If all of these are false, we can diverge (we must diverge, actually), but if any of these is true, we must halt. We can not proceed with a simple infinite iteration, since $f(1)$ might diverge and $f(2)$ might return $x$, and if so we need to detect that and halt anyway.

So, we need to evaluate *in parallel* all these programs, so that even if one of them diverges does not stop the evaluation of the others.

Think of a fair scheduler among infinitely many processes. Think about running a program for only a given number of steps. Think about doves and their tails. ;-)

Comment: I am using this definition: A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}^k$ is RE iff there is a turing machine $M$ such that for $x \in A$, $M$ with input $x$ halts, giving output $1$ and for $x \notin A$ , $M$ does not halt. So do we deduce that the domain of a recursive function is recursive?

Comment: So, for the second question: Let $x \in range (f)$, where $f$ is a recursive function. Suppose that we have so many tapes, as the number of elements of the domain. Since $f$ is recursive, there is a Turing machine $M$ that computes it. We run simultaneously $M$ on the different elements of the domain at the tapes. If $M$ halts at some  tape,  the Turing machine  should halt on $x$, otherwise it should not. Right?

Comment: @Evinda You can't add infinitely many tapes, that is too much. It would enable a TM to compute any arbitrary function. But you can keep $k$ representation of tapes on a single tape, and increment $k$ every so often. In such way, at any given time you only use a finite amount of memory, but eventually $k$ will be large enough to run every TM you want to simulate.

Comment: @Evinda We don't deduce the domain is R but is RE. The proof is what you wrote in the question, except that you need to ensure the output is $1$ to comply with the definition. Just compute $f(n)\cdot 0 + 1$, which is recursive as well and has the right domain and output.

Comment: If we have a single tape that constains $k$ tapes, how can we run simultaneously the machine at each tape? $$$$
Can we say that $A$ with an input that does not belong in the domain of $f$ gives output $\infty$ ?

Comment: How can an OS run multiple processes with one CPU?